# How open-ssh can connect through SOCKS5 proxy on windows (Putty is not an option)?

Tags: ssh

**What I want**

```
          shadowsocks connection (SOCKS5)
        127.0.0.1:1080 -------> SERVEUR:YYY
       (WINDOWS)                (LINUX / ARCH)
        /                              \
      ssh                              sshd
```

**What works**

I can ssh login on LINUX from WINDOWS through SOCKS5 proxy using Putty (proxy: SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:1080)

**The problem**

Visual code does not support putty !

I installed Open-ssh for windows (OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5)
and tried everything I could using ProxyCommand and ncat.exe ... nothing works ...

Ncat 7.91 for windows

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\laurentb/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\laurentb/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for home
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 127.0.0.1 is address
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nmap\\ncat.exe --proxy-type socks5 --proxy 127.0.0.1:1080 127.0.0.1
debug3: spawning "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nmap\\ncat.exe" --proxy-type socks5 --proxy 127.0.0.1:1080 127.0.0.1
debug3: w32_getpeername ERROR: not sock :2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\laurentb\\.ssh\\remote_auth type 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/laurentb/.ssh/remote_auth-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/laurentb/.ssh/remote_auth-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\laurentb\\.ssh\\remote_auth-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

**QUESTION**

Does anybody managed to log using OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1 ssh through a SOCKS5 proxy and how ?

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question:

Since putty is working well : use Putty to forward 22 port through SOCKS5

A) proxy :

- SOCKS 5
- hostname : 127.0.0.1
- port:1080

[image: snapshot putty conf]

B ) forward port L22 127.0.0.1:22

[image: snapshot putty conf]

C) ssh to 127.0.0.1:22
ssh -l "username" 127.0.0.1

**You can this way use Remote Visual Studio Code through shadowsocks proxy...**